# Flask / Jinja2 - best pratice of HTML escaping

Tags: python, html, flask, escaping, jinja2

I'm using Flask to build a webapplication with a database in the backend. Which data do I need to escape to ensure no sitemanipulations like XSS?

The Jinja2 template engine provides the '|safe' filter to ensure such escaping. With comments and other stuff, that the user can edit (and possibly manipulate), it seeems logically to escape, but are other content vulnerable too? Which filters, extenions or tricks should be used especially in the context of Flask and Jinja2?

Comment: Beware: the safe filter is used to indicate that a variable does NOT need escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to enable automatic filtering using the `autoescape` extension. From [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#autoescaping):

```
env = Environment(autoescape=guess_autoescape,
                  loader=PackageLoader('mypackage'),
                  extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])
```

This has *some* performance overhead, but experience shows us that is **very** easy to forget to escape that one variable, which gives us an XSS (even large sites, like eBay, have fallen victim to this).

This also answers your question, 'what should be escaped?'. In larger applications, it's often not easy to determine what variables can be directly (or indirectly!) influenced by users. In addition, escaping is not just a security feature, since a fixed string such as `This is a <test> & a string` also needs escaping for the `<` and `&`.

You can still print HTML with the `safe` filter, ie. `my_string|safe`.

**Edit: reply to your questions:**

> 1. Would it be overkill to escape even the userstring or similar things?

What if my username is `<script>alert('boo!')</script>`? Or if it is `&fancy&`? I suppose you could get around that by disallowing certain characters during registration, but are you *sure* there's no way to circumvent this? What if I fill in `\x26`  in my username? Or what if you can get around the check some other way? What if (in the future) you want to allow such characters, or in the future you connect with an external login service (facebook, google, github) that allows such characters?

Yes, there is a (small) performance overhead, but it's more secure, and it's easier to program. The whole point of environments like Python & Jinja is to optimize programmer productivity at the expense of performance :)

> 2. Some webapplications with a database are administrated with tools like phmyadmin (which some folks forget to remove or protect). With this scenario a hacker could manipulate data inside the database without touching the application itself. Would this worst case and its damage reduced by escaping everything (see 1.)

Yes. This is obviously something of a disaster. However, if an attacker gains full access to your database then he/she probably doesn't need to bother with XSS attacks, since all data is already at his/her fingertips.
However, there is a less malicious way things can go wrong, for example, an administrator manually created (or edits) a User with a character that needs escaping.

Comment: 1. Would it be overkill to escape even the userstring or similar things?

2. Some webapplications with a database are administrated with tools like phmyadmin (which some folks forget to remove or protect). With this scenario a hacker could manipulate data inside the database without touching the application itself. Would this worst case and its damage reduced by escaping everything (see 1.)

Comment: @user3147268 I have edited my answer to answer your questions, since the answers are rather long :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. In short - **Escape everything you can** right?

Comment: @user3147268 Yes, that would sum my advice up in a few words :)

Comment: Flask enables auto-escaping by default.

Comment: What do I do with that `env` variable? Do I pass it to `app = Flask(__name__)` or `render_template(filename, **args)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block body %}
{{ data|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I saw this already in the docs. But do I need it everytime, when I ouput any data from the database?

Usually every programmer should check the input, but only to be sure.